# Is there any way to restart MongoDB version 5.0 without rebuilding indexes from scratch?

Tags: mongodb

I have a standalone deployment of MongoDB which runs on MongoDB 5.0. Due to some issue, mongod service crashed which was fixed. But the problem is, mongod service takes forever to restart because it is building all the indexes from scratch. For now, the daemon is running with no issues. But waiting for hours just for restarting the mongo daemon on next crash is not worth it.

Prior to MongoDB v4.4, there was a setting in mongod.conf `indexBuildRetry` which skipped the index building. Thanks.

Comment: Change to a replica set to have high availability.  The setting `indexBuildRetry` was intended for incomplete indexes.  If you were building an index and the process died then upon restart-up the  index would be recreated.  Do you have any indexes that are incomplete?  This option should never try to rebuild a complete index.  How did you conclude the indexes were being created and this is the cause of the slowness?  Does your code include attributes to instruct creation of indexes?  Do you use any deployment tooling and/or Continuous Integration that might create indexes?

Comment: Well, it did try rebuilding complete indexes. I have tried this by intentionally stopping the daemon when there was no operation running on it. Still, it took forever.

Answer (score 0):

If a node in a replica set is cleanly shutdown or rolls back during an index build, the index build progress is now saved to disk. When the server restarts, index creation resumes from the saved position.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-creation/#std-label-index-operations-build-failure